# Special conformal transformation convention

Tags: operators, conventions, conformal-field-theory

This is a question not about the Physics (or Math) but about the convention. One usually defines (as in the yellow book Di Francesco) the special conformal transformation (SCT) as
\begin{equation}
 x^{'\mu} = \frac{x^\mu - x^2 b^\mu}{1 - 2x\cdot b + x^2 b^2}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
 \frac{x^{'\mu}}{x^{'2}} = \frac{x^{\mu}}{x^{2}} - b^\mu
\end{equation}
It's essentially a translation conjugated by an inversion, but with a minus sign compared to the usually definition of translation. To be more precise we usually define $P_\mu=\partial_\mu$ as the Killing vector for translation and $K_\mu=2x_\mu x^\nu\partial_\nu - x^2\partial_\mu$ (not $-2x_\mu x^\nu\partial_\nu + x^2\partial_\mu$) as the Killing vector for SCT. So under the conjugation by inversion we have
\begin{equation}
 P_\mu \to -K_\mu, \; K_\mu \to - P_\mu
\end{equation}
It seems not as simple as it can be with the extra minus sign. I am wondering if there is any reason we stick to the current convention.